# My Mac mini restart or shutdown suddenly. And a bunch of folder appear on screen when I turn it on again

Tags: crash, mac-mini, error

I notice that my Mac mini 2018 has random restarted or shut down suddenly even while I'm working or don't do anything. When turn it on again I see this log:

[image]

And my desktop appear a lot of weird folder like this, now they're not appear when the os crashed, sometimes it appear when I turn on my machine:

Have to talk with Apple Supporter and they told me to reset NVRAM, PRAM but it's still error.

[image]

Additional info (A few months ago I has dropped my machine when put it in a backpack.):
[image]

Comment: Adobe CC 2019 doesn't work properly on Catalina. That's not going to help.

Comment: @Tetsujin you mean adobe cc 2019 is the reason make my OS crash randomly?

Comment: It might be; Adobe certainly don't support it on Catalina & tell everybody to update, as there is no reason to still be running 2019 at all; CC is a 'rental' not a one-off purchase. Updating to 2020 will certainly eliminate it as the problem.